# How to Prevent Selenium WebElement sendKeys() Method from Performing Parameter Substitution

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium automation to test malicious strings that an attacker might send. However, I've run into an issue with the method [`WebDriver.sendKeys(...)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#sendKeys-java.lang.CharSequence...-) where the text value is not sent to the browser literally.

For example, the string `../../../../../../../../../../../etc/hosts` is being automatically modified so that the text in the browser resembles `/var/folders/<...>/hosts` instead.

The code that causes the problem:

```
public void enterCommentText(String text) {    
    WebElement textArea = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathForCommentTextArea()));
    textArea.clear();
    textArea.sendKeys(text);
}
```

When `textArea.sendKeys(text)` is called, the string `text` contains the literal file path that I want to send. However, the string that appears in the browser has undergone parameter substitution. Is there a way to make `sendKeys(text)` process a string value literally?

My current workaround is to send each character from the string one at a time.

```
for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
    textArea.sendKeys(text.substring(i, i+1));
}
```

I'm working with Java 8, Selenium 3.8.1, and Chrome 64.0.3282.186.

Comment: What was the code before the workaround? As sending a string should just send a string.

Comment: Added it to the original description.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean that the field `text` contains the desired literal, but `textArea.sendKeys(text)` performs parameter substitution?

Comment: Yes, text = "../../../../../../../../../../../etc/hosts", after sendKeys() runs, the text in the browser looks like "/var/folders/..../hosts".

Answer (score 2):

After repeated tries, I am unable to reproduce the issue. `sendKeys()` is always sending the original path string and not being modified.

Things to try are:

(1) Add a few (one before `.sendKeys()` and one after) `System.out.println("Test:" + text);` in the method to verify that it's coming in correct and not modified earlier in the process,

(2) Try a different browser,

(3) Try the same code but on a different page such as `http://www.globalsqa.com/samplepagetest/` to see if it's the app you are testing trying to interpret things.

Comment: From my investigations:
(1) The text is correct before being sent to .sendKeys()
(2) The issue was not related to a particular browser
(3) The issue was not in the app.

I'm guessing the issue has something to do with either my IDE or how the project is being built. I've decided to leave things with my original workaround that sends the characters one at a time.